# Android Studio, Chipmunk, Bluetooth, Java

Tags: java, android-studio

I am new to Stackoverflow.

I get the following error and do not understand why:

incompatible types:  cannot be converted to Context

Code snippet:

```
           if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
                if (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED != ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT)) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return;
                }
```

The error line did not show up!
The error line is:
if (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED != ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT)) {

I have permissions set in my .xml file.
I am very new to Android Studio!

Event Log output:
C:\Users\jsla3009\AndroidStudioProjects\Test_Bluetooth\app\src\main\java\com\example\test_bluetooth\MainActivity.java:97: error: incompatible types:  cannot be converted to Context
if (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED != ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT)) {
^
C:\Users\jsla3009\AndroidStudioProjects\Test_Bluetooth\app\src\main\java\com\example\test_bluetooth\MainActivity.java:
uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
C:\Users\jsla3009\AndroidStudioProjects\Test_Bluetooth\app\src\main\java\com\example\test_bluetooth\MainActivity.java:
uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output

Answer (score 0):

`this` always references the object you are currently in.

Your error means that you are trying to pass something other than a `Context` as your first argument in `checkSelfPermission`, which means that `this` is not a `Context`.

1. Check that `MainActivity` extends `Context` or some subclass of it, e.g. `AppCompatActivity`.
2. Check that your code is not inside of an [anonymous class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html). If it is, use `MainActivity.this` instead of `this` to clarify you mean to pass the MainActivity instance and not the instance of your anonymous class.

If that doesn't help, please share your entire class!